# Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in LOCALHOST?

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf, tcpdf

Estoy generando cuestionarios con ayuda de TCPDF en PHP y MySQL. Utilizo esta forma ya que estoy generando dichos reportes PDF de datos almacenados de una base de datos de mysql. Cada reporte se genera con 4 hojas cada uno  y actualmente intente generar 122 reportes a lo cual el tiempo de respuesta se ha exedido.

El error lanzado de localhost fue:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\TCPDF-master\tcpdf.php on line 18295
```

Me gustaría saber como puedo solucionar lo anterior ya que realmente necesito generar estos reportes de esta forma en mi sistema.

Dejaré el archivo php que genera dichos reportes:

```
 <?php  
 session_start();
 function fetch_data()  
{  
$output = '';  
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mydbname"); 
$conn -> set_charset("utf8"); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM texto_mas50 T INNER JOIN empresasregistradas E ON T.pin = E.pin WHERE T.pin ='{$_SESSION['pin']}' ORDER BY T.pin ASC";  
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
{      
    $output .= '
    <img src="img/NOM035Logo.png" style="width: 1200%"> 
    <h2 align="center">Cuestionario: Identificación de los factores de riesgo psicosocial y evaluar el entorno organizacional.</h2><br><br><br><br>

    <b>Centro de Trabajo: </b>'.$row["nombre_empresa"].'<br><br>
    <b>Fecha de aplicación: </b>'.$row["fecha_aplicacion"].'<br><br>
    <b>PIN: </b>'.$row["pin"].'<br><br><br><br><br>
    <b>Instrucciones:</b><br>
     Por favor conteste todas las preguntas.<br><br>
    <h4><strong>Para responder las preguntas siguientes considere las condiciones ambientales de su centro de trabajo.</strong></h4><br><br>
    <b>1.</b> El espacio donde trabajo me permite realizar mis actividades de manera segura e higiénica:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r1"].'<br><br>
    <b>2.</b> Mi trabajo me exige hacer mucho esfuerzo físico:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r2"].'<br><br>
    <b>3.</b> Me preocupa sufrir un accidente en mi trabajo:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r3"].'<br><br>
    <b>4.</b>Considero que en mi trabajo se aplican las normas de seguridad y salud en el trabajo:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r4"].'<br><br>
    <b>5.</b>Considero que las actividades que realizo son peligrosas:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r5"].'<br>
    <h4><strong>Para responder a las preguntas siguientes piense en la cantidad y ritmo de trabajo que tiene.</strong></h4><br><br> 
    <b>6.</b>Por la cantidad de trabajo que tengo debo quedarme tiempo adicional a mi turno:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r6"].'<br><br>
    <b>7.</b>Por la cantidad de trabajo que tengo debo trabajar sin parar:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r7"].'<br><br>
    <b>8.</b>Considero que es necesario mantener un ritmo de trabajo acelerado:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r8"].'<br>
    <h4><strong>Las preguntas siguientes están relacionadas con el esfuerzo mental que le exige su trabajo.</strong></h4><br><br>
    <b>9.</b>Mi trabajo exige que esté muy concentrado:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r9"].'<br><br>
    <b>10.</b>Mi trabajo requiere que memorice mucha información:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r10"].'<br><br>
    <b>11.</b>En mi trabajo tengo que tomar decisiones difíciles muy rápido:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r11"].'<br><br>
    <b>12.</b>Mi trabajo exige que atienda varios asuntos al mismo tiempo:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r12"].'<br>
    <h4><strong>Las preguntas siguientes están relacionadas con las actividades que realiza en su trabajo y las responsabilidades que tiene.</strong></h4><br><br>
    <b>13.</b>En mi trabajo soy responsable de cosas de mucho valor:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r13"].'<br><br>
    <b>14.</b>Respondo ante mi jefe por los resultados de toda mi área de trabajo:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r14"].'<br><br>
    <b>15.</b>En el trabajo me dan órdenes contradictorias:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r15"].'<br><br>
    <b>16.</b>Considero que en mi trabajo me piden hacer cosas innecesarias:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r16"].'<br>
    <h4><strong>Las preguntas siguientes están relacionadas con su jornada de trabajo.</strong></h4><br><br>
    <b>17.</b>Trabajo horas extras más de tres veces a la semana:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r17"].'<br><br>
    <b>18.</b>Mi trabajo me exige laborar en días de descanso, festivos o fines de semana:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r18"].'<br><br>
    <b>19.</b>Considero que el tiempo en el trabajo es mucho y perjudica mis actividades familiares o personales:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r19"].'<br><br>
    <b>20.</b>Debo atender asuntos de trabajo cuando estoy en casa:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r20"].'<br><br>
    <b>21.</b>Pienso en las actividades familiares o personales cuando estoy en mi trabajo:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r21"].'<br><br>
    <b>22.</b>Pienso que mis responsabilidades familiares afectan mi trabajo:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r22"].'<br><br>
    <h4><strong>Las preguntas siguientes están relacionadas con las decisiones que puede tomar en su trabajo.</strong></h4><br><br>
    <b>23.</b>Mi trabajo permite que desarrolle nuevas habilidades:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r23"].'<br><br>
    <b>24.</b>En mi trabajo puedo aspirar a un mejor puesto:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r24"].'<br><br>
    <b>25.</b>Durante mi jornada de trabajo puedo tomar pausas cuando las necesito:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r25"].'<br><br>
    <b>26.</b>Puedo decidir cuánto trabajo realizo durante la jornada laboral:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r26"].'<br><br>
    <b>27.</b>Puedo decidir la velocidad a la que realizo mis actividades en mi trabajo:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r27"].'<br><br>
    <b>28.</b>Puedo cambiar el orden de las actividades que realizo en mi trabajo:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r28"].'<br>
    <h4><strong>Las preguntas siguientes están relacionadas con cualquier tipo de cambio que ocurra en su trabajo (considere los últimos cambios realizados).</strong></h4><br><br>
    <b>29.</b>Los cambios que se presentan en mi trabajo dificultan mi labor:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r29"].'<br><br>
    <b>30.</b>Cuando se presentan cambios en mi trabajo se tienen en cuenta mis ideas o aportaciones:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r30"].'<br>
    <h4><strong>Las preguntas siguientes están relacionadas con la capacitación e información que se le proporciona sobre su trabajo.</strong></h4><br><br>
    <b>31.</b>Me informan con claridad cuáles son mis funciones:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r31"].'<br><br>
    <b>32.</b>Me explican claramente los resultados que debo obtener en mi trabajo:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r32"].'<br><br>
    <b>33.</b>Me explican claramente los objetivos de mi trabajo:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r33"].'<br><br>
    <b>34.</b>Me informan con quién puedo resolver problemas o asuntos de trabajo:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["34"].'<br><br>
    <b>35.</b>Me permiten asistir a capacitaciones relacionadas con mi trabajo:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r35"].'<br><br>
    <b>36.</b>Recibo capacitación útil para hacer mi trabajo:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r36"].'<br>
    <h4><strong>Las preguntas siguientes están relacionadas con el o los jefes con quien tiene contacto.</strong></h4><br><br>
    <b>37.</b>Mi jefe ayuda a organizar mejor el trabajo:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r37"].'<br><br>
    <b>38.</b>Mi jefe tiene en cuenta mis puntos de vista y opiniones:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r38"].'<br><br>
    <b>39.</b>Mi jefe me comunica a tiempo la información relacionada con el trabajo:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r39"].'<br><br>
    <b>40.</b>La orientación que me da mi jefe me ayuda a realizar mejor mi trabajo:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r40"].'<br><br>
    <b>41.</b>Mi jefe ayuda a solucionar los problemas que se presentan en el trabajo:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r41"].'<br><br>
    <h4><strong>Las preguntas siguientes se refieren a las relaciones con sus compañeros.</strong></h4><br><br>
    <b>42.</b>Puedo confiar en mis compañeros de trabajo:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r42"].'<br><br>
    <b>43.</b>Entre compañeros solucionamos los problemas del trabajo de forma respetuosa:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r43"].'<br><br>
    <b>44.</b>En mi trabajo me hacen sentir parte del grupo:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r44"].'<br><br>
    <b>45.</b>Cuando tenemos que realizar trabajo de equipo los compañeros colaboran:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r45"].'<br><br>
    <b>46.</b>Mis compañeros de trabajo me ayudan cuando tengo dificultades:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r46"].'<br>
    <h4><strong>Las preguntas siguientes están relacionadas con la información que recibe sobre su rendimiento en el trabajo, el reconocimiento, el sentido de pertenencia y la estabilidad que le ofrece su trabajo.</strong></h4><br><br>
    <b>47.</b>Me informan sobre lo que hago bien en mi trabajo:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r47"].'<br><br>
    <b>48.</b>La forma como evalúan mi trabajo en mi centro de trabajo me ayuda a mejorar mi desempeño:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r48"].'<br><br>
    <b>49.</b>En mi centro de trabajo me pagan a tiempo mi salario:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r49"].'<br><br>
    <b>50.</b>El pago que recibo es el que merezco por el trabajo que realizo:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r50"].'<br><br>
    <b>51.</b>Si obtengo los resultados esperados en mi trabajo me recompensan o reconocen:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r51"].'<br><br>
    <b>52.</b>Las personas que hacen bien el trabajo pueden crecer laboralmente:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r52"].'<br><br>
    <b>53.</b>Considero que mi trabajo es estable:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r53"].'<br><br>
    <b>54.</b>En mi trabajo existe continua rotación de personal:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r54"].'<br><br>
    <b>55.</b>Siento orgullo de laborar en este centro de trabajo:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r55"].'<br><br>
    <b>56.</b>Me siento comprometido con mi trabajo:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r56"].'<br>
    <h4><strong>Las preguntas siguientes están relacionadas con actos de violencia laboral (malos tratos, acoso, hostigamiento, acoso psicológico).</strong></h4><br><br>
    <b>57.</b>En mi trabajo puedo expresarme libremente sin interrupciones:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r57"].'<br><br>
    <b>58.</b>Recibo críticas constantes a mi persona y/o trabajo:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r58"].'<br><br>
    <b>59.</b>Recibo burlas, calumnias, difamaciones, humillaciones o ridiculizaciones:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r59"].'<br><br>
    <b>60.</b>Se ignora mi presencia o se me excluye de las reuniones de trabajo y en la toma de decisiones:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r60"].'<br><br>
    <b>61.</b>Se manipulan las situaciones de trabajo para hacerme parecer un mal trabajador:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r61"].'<br><br>
    <b>62.</b>Se ignoran mis éxitos laborales y se atribuyen a otros trabajadores:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r62"].'<br><br>
    <b>63.</b>Me bloquean o impiden las oportunidades que tengo para obtener ascenso o mejora en mi trabajo:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r63"].'<br><br>
    <b>64.</b>He presenciado actos de violencia en mi centro de trabajo:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r64"].'<br>
    <h4><strong>Las preguntas siguientes están relacionadas con la atención a clientes y usuarios.</strong></h4><br><br>
    <b>65.</b>Atiendo clientes o usuarios muy enojados:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r65"].'<br><br>
    <b>66.</b>Mi trabajo me exige atender personas muy necesitadas de ayuda o enfermas:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r66"].'<br><br>
    <b>67.</b>Para hacer mi trabajo debo demostrar sentimientos distintos a los míos:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r67"].'<br><br>
    <b>68.</b>Se ignora mi presencia o se me excluye de las reuniones de trabajo y en la toma de decisiones:<br><br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r68"].'<br>
    <h4><strong>Las preguntas siguientes están relacionadas con las actitudes de las personas que supervisa.</strong></h4><br><br>
    <b>69.</b>Comunican tarde los asuntos de trabajo:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r69"].'<br><br>
    <b>70.</b>Dificultan el logro de los resultados del trabajo:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r70"].'<br><br>
    <b>71.</b>Cooperan poco cuando se necesita:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r71"].'<br><br>
    <b>72.</b>Ignoran las sugerencias para mejorar su trabajo:<br>
     Respuesta:'.$row["r72"].'<br>


    <b>-Genero: </b>'.$row["genero"].'<br>
    <b>-Edad en años: </b>'.$row["edad"].'<br>
    <b>-Estado Civil: </b>'.$row["estado_civil"].'<br>
    <b>-Nivel de estudios: </b>'.$row["nivel_estudios"].'<br>
    <b>-Departamento/Sección/Área: </b>'.$row["departamento"].'<br>
    <b>-Tipo de Puesto: </b>'.$row["tipo_puesto"].'<br>
    <b>-Tipo de Contrato: </b>'.$row["tipo_contratacion"].'<br>
    <b>-Tipo de Personal: </b>'.$row["tipo_personal"].'<br>
    <b>-Tipo de Jornada de trabajo: </b>'.$row["tipo_jornada"].'<br>
    <b>-Realiza rotación de turnos: </b>'.$row["rotacion"].'<br>
    <b>-Experiencia (años) en el puesto actual: </b>'.$row["experiencia_actual"].'<br>
    <b>-Tiempo experiencia laboral: </b>'.$row["experiencia_total"].'<br>
    <b>-Nombre Oficina / Centro de Trabajo / Sucursal: </b>'.$row["nombre_oficina"].'<br>
    <b>-Código Postal de la oficina / Centro de Trabajo / Sucursal: </b>'.$row["cp_oficina"].'

  ';  
  }  
  return $output;  
 }  
 if(isset($_POST["generate_pdf"]))  
 {  
 require_once('TCPDF-master/tcpdf.php');  
 $obj_pdf = new TCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);  
 $obj_pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);  
 $obj_pdf->SetTitle("Generar Reporte PDF de los cuestionarios realizados NOM-035.");  
 $obj_pdf->SetHeaderData('', '', PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);  
 $obj_pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));  
 $obj_pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));  
 $obj_pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');  
 $obj_pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);  
 $obj_pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, '10', PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);  
 $obj_pdf->setPrintHeader(false);  
 $obj_pdf->setPrintFooter(false);  
 $obj_pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 10);  
 $obj_pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 9);  
 $obj_pdf->AddPage();  
 $content = '';  
 $content .= "";  
 $content .= fetch_data();  

 $obj_pdf->writeHTML($content);  
 $obj_pdf->Output('Reporte de Cuestionarios.pdf', 'I');  
 }  
 ?>
```

Comment: El error te dice que has excedido el tiempo de procesamiento asignado al PHP. Este tiempo lo puedes configurar en tu PHP.ini. aumentas el tiempo a lo que necesites. Sin embargo, este tipo de procesos suelen hacerse en consumidores, de manera que tú mandas un mensaje a un dispacher (ej, rabbitmq) y luego tu consumer procesa el archivo con la info del mensaje. Te recomiendo que busques información respecto consumers y rabbitmq

Comment: Lo fácil es hacer que espere el usuario, lo correcto es mejorar el desempeño ¿Tienes índices sobre la columna `pin`?

Comment: @Sal sólo es un campo de tipo varchar que acompaña a otros datos. Este tipo de dato no se repite.

Comment: No es lo mismo un índice que una restricción; los primeros son para mejorar el desempeño, los segundos son para garantizar integridad de datos. En ciertos casos las restricciones se basan en un índice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para solucionar el problema, busca en tu archivo php.ini la siguiente linea **max_execution_time** y cambia su estado, que por defecto es 30 a 60 o 80. De necesitar un poco mas se puede aumentar.